# univarsal link not working in iOS after / any absolute string

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

universal link working with a domain but any absolute string it will redirect to the browser

https://example.com   This link is working and click to open the app

but

https://example.com/AAbcZ3ac This link is not open my app when I click it will open in browser

apple-app-site-association file looks like-

```
{
"applinks": {
    "apps": [ ],
    "details": [
        {
            "appID": "{app_prefix}.{app_identifier}",
            "paths": [ "*" ]
        }
    ]
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding this code in your paths

["*", "/"]

Comment: it's working fine, the actual problem is when you test any universal  link and any changes it will not work whenever uninstall app restart device.

Comment: Okay Great @amit.mishra

Answer (score 0):

Anything you want to add in your path to working properly when you change your path in the AASA file you can uninstall the app and restart your device first and check it will work fine.

you won't use anything your path on the basis of your requirements.

"paths": [ "*","/*","/" ]